# unwanted chinese/korean program installed unable to remove it from any where

Tags: laptop, troubleshooting, malware, adware, avg-antivirus

members some unknown Chinese program has uninstalled in my system I have tried many antivirus and malware removal programs without any clue as what this program is. Finally I am posting a screenshot of the popup this program gives.
Please see following screenshots to understand what I am saying https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1JJUfLfFwrLZzljbHNpSUJKLWs

Due to interruption from this chinese program I am unable to work properly on my laptop. A pop up frequently comes and I have no clue what to do. Unfortunately it also does not show me the program listed in the list of installed programs. I have scanned the laptop with Malware bytes fully but there is no success.

*update* 
As per suggestion below I have been able to solve this problem but only an icon QQPCtray.exe exists in notifications bar , The problem is 95% solved. I am left with only QQPCTray.exe showing in Notifications bar. A snapshot is here https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1JJUfLfFwrLQXBkYV8yOUcxYUk/view?usp=sharing the tencent program has been uninstalled. I have manually deleted C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\Tencent folder but I get to see QQPCTray in the notifications bar still. So how to delete this from notifications bar as you see in screenshot above.

Comment: Yes that happened to me. I was installing a program and like a dummy I gave it "administrative" privileges. I restarted my PC in safe mode with networking. Then opened programs and searched for programs installed on that day and uninstalled them all. You can look up their processes in Task Manager (ctrl+alt+del) and kill tree. Then ran full drive checks with Security Essentials and another with the free Malware Bytes program (full scan on both, but do UPDATES first to get all current definitions of threats). Then let both programs delete all the bad files. Restarted and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I [reverse-image searched](https://www.google.ca/search?tbs=sbi:AMhZZitoFdrEr2gXDGi6pYVCT2FrZYej-nMUUEGrQKHkYlCaCq7UCZHSH2uZmjqwcF7yGyEWskR7Vu8eWWMnuPnNQu65viHyERrZPlwKBw-owTicRk_1HBTWoCAtUNkGaSo_1bNECMLJXmzHFIuXCXhAxZ8rXlLu1BpEvy1cWV5e2kkC3QPlLMR-HQrXIIC8YIY8BZoUacE0QiB9JsboIhEtyvO_1AsuLfrAehYsoWUYG8PcQNzvtR5RiLiknnUmQs8b5y4iCbKaAmjowWgH5Vtfs46wHRQZ7wiN1Woc6bFSGNqCOhRmWq49FRE4Bscks_1YspWhBerb04sEOQ0SHSC0RZlgp_1HpvExG_1937qGk9-nR8dbW2z69KYcQZ2hwHni0NHE1L1K8fhK-h1SCHPP8VbXIXME6vuhDeV3HoMputZMBH4SR8fx8Eh6fQ_1iPaYuz4a2TQ5Y3ercT-nb6RJh12-E1M3diC5JeBgGYulWn7eJPiuXAsBAuME_16HQ_1P3j7QZ9nOjJfM2skquSAQHPCsAVl8Sj4D3CDRIljbyh-xU5sYSI0PtH7BdndRUYr3LdG_1vLuGbkghb7BTHgo1AGOFJ_1UR6LBilhPh0EDeqBBMOphXbZgCPQpcVy0iEZz7F9upjrVF8bd4BuxrZ9EDgN_15e-bzBopT8L0kiMuw-z0zdJMZcCLz8pI_1EAN8InSaPn2YKB3wjNaT0cZCH1mTBerviGhdsVERdwc9MKISU51OiJajrLrnlYcGe1ykh4aU-zj72tM7s5M2fSRDSW56CvMzXit6mRw7kvmJXldWDW4Xn2_1p4YMRHF91W5i-3MIGa0pZFqqJmNPCNlUC9J5jDes4mi-2YgmYc0e5S3iovIP14dI-YBu0RRYfv0ukqrV1fSdGmictUpcbJ5297o1XaHvo6HYGEMJ5o9NEpY6Nqvd3ii_1fI2K00nA19Ef1QVH8LCcxWsMg6g9PoI5RiwuKvw5sC9KI34RUwwvBwJBTPCrrEz2U03OW7Fws2-O0Yk48XL5s9YcMk3VMJerHc4JvQSKVO5iKZds8CRNjaxJtNksSdppshPaJXLCpOTYDnjuehWDaWyJBOQPlkp3cNcSAbHgpXG2WTTfOgDClK9zSIua32Tgi6XiI3zgckGKqhYevhaalE2c6EQR5f6XfijwtpgFT49JEicxNSNw97I19G9DZ9wPchUaAjUYe4WGcnD7772vicqVgfHM24PrFU66nQxtFit4n81y5GpC9kf3snz1GQ7lA_1-Vr1UgDczrU&=Search%20by%20image) the icon:

[image]

and it turns out the program is "Tencent (QQ)PCMgr".

> "Tencent PC Manager is a free antivirus program available for for Windows (32-bit and 64-bit) operating system, it is created by Tencent Technology(Shenzhen) Company Limited and claims to help the computer user to protect their PCs well from dangerous viruses, malware and other emerging threats. So it not a malware or threat for the computer which has it installed"

.

> "Tencent QQ is an anti-virus tool, developed by Chinese company Shenzhen Limited. This tool is completely free, and even useful, but it is so, only if you speak Chinese!"

And there are dozens of results [showing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4PzxLPmFIgY), [how to](http://pcfixhelp.net/viruses/2607-how-to-remove-tencent-qq), [remove it](http://www.totaluninstaller.com/program-uninstall-center/clean-uninstall-tencent-pc-manager-thoroughly-pc/).

Most of them seem to suggest to remove it by either using Add/Remove programs, or by running its uninstaller directly from the software's folder:

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for pointing this out. I did not knew a reverse image search existed.  The problem is 95% solved. I am left with only QQPCTray.exe showing in Notifications bar. A snapshot is here https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1JJUfLfFwrLQXBkYV8yOUcxYUk/view?usp=sharing the tencent program has been uninstalled. I have manually deleted C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\Tencent folder but I get to see QQPCTray in the notifications bar still.

Comment: Just because a program claims to be harmless does not mean it actually is.  Furthermore, malware often masks itself by pretending to be any widely used legitimate software, so having the appearance of a legitimate program doesn't rule out a Trojan either.

Answer (score 1):

Yes that happened to me. I was installing a program and like a dummy I gave it "administrative" privileges.

**Solution:**

1. Make sure Microsoft Security Essentials is installed. Install Malware Bytes (free version).
2. Restart PC in safe mode with networking.
3. Open "installed programs" and searched for programs installed on
   that day and uninstall them all if able.  OR: You can look up their
   processes in Task Manager (ctrl+alt+del) and kill tree, then
   uninstall if possible. This seems like a solution, but many of these programs have already embedded self-installs/self re-installs that are hidden.
4. Open Security Essentials and do UPDATES. Same with Malware Bytes,
   UPDATES.
5. Run full drive checks with Security Essentials and another with the
   free Malware Bytes program.
6. Then let both programs detect and delete all the bad files.
7. When both programs have run in safe mode and deleted all threats,
   and only then, You can restart your PC and the problem should be
   solved.

Comment: That seems more a genetic approach then a specific solution. Btw it can be useful too. ;)

Comment: @Hastur It's exactly what happened to me. A program in Chinese installed a bunch of programs that started with QQ and other things. I tried killing the tasks but it didn't work, they kept popping up and installing more and more. The solution I provided solved it in a way that a technician would solve it. The next step would be to to initiate a recover point assuming one was initiated at an earlier date. I usually create a recovery point before installing any software I download over the internet; as a precaution for recovery.